# Codeigniter Routes Not Working In Subdirectory

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi for some reason on my routes it is not picking up the thrid level of folder for my admin routes. I have been reading through  user guide but not quite sure on it yet.

**Error: The page you requested was not found.**

Controllers

```
admin > 
admin > common >
admin > common > header.php
admin > common > footer.php
admin > common > home.php <!-- need route to go here can not find page
```

Routes

```
$route['default_controller'] = "admin/common/home";
$route['admin/common/home'] = "Administration";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

I had a look here not sure?
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      // Your own constructor code
   }

   public function index() {

    $this->data['header'] = $this->load->view('admin/common/header', NULL, TRUE);
    $this->data['footer'] = $this->load->view('admin/common/footer', NULL, TRUE);

    $this->load->view('admin/common/home', $this->data);

   }
}
```

Comment: whats on your controller?

Comment: @majimboo I have edited above what's on home controller.

Comment: You should have an admin controller that deals with loading common/home, it looks like you are using home/index to load admin/common/home. When you access home/index what page is loaded in the browser?

Comment: If you look above there is

Comment: what goes in the default_controller

Comment: tried it still errors

Comment: Give me a few minutes to compile a reply to this issue.

Comment: default controller doesn't work in sub dirs.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out:

**Your Configuration: (config/routes.php)**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "admin/common/home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

**Your Controller Should be: (application/controllers/admin.php)**

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      // Your own constructor code
   }

   public function index() {

   $this->data['header'] = $this->load->view('admin/common/header', NULL, TRUE);
   $this->data['footer'] = $this->load->view('admin/common/footer', NULL, TRUE);

   $this->load->view('admin/common/home', $this->data);
   }
}
```

**Now in your view folder you need to have an admin folder with the following structure:**

```
admin
admin/common
  - header.php
  - home.php
  - footer.php
```

If you wish to add pages to the admin controller just make sure you add the required files in the view folder.

EDIT: I noticed you were using the data to load the header/footer I updated and re-added that.

Comment: But I have a controller for each header.php home.php and footer.php Are you talking about base controller?

Comment: I was talking about the overall structure, You have a Home controller but your calling a view from a different folder. My apologies if I'm not understanding your issue, I can't see the entire project layout in my mind.

Comment: @user3475662 It's 1:13am and I need to get some rest, I will check on this post tomorrow.